# R: How to set position-option in tabular via xtable?

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

Using xtable the following code

```
  \documentclass{article}

  \begin{document}

  <<>>=
  myData <- matrix(c(1,2,3,11,12,13,111,222,33),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
  colnames(myData) <- c("A","B","C")
  @

  <<echo=FALSE>>=
  library("xtable")
  xt <- xtable(myData, align="|l|r|r|r|", digits=0)

  out <- print(xt, print.results = FALSE, floating = FALSE)
  @

  \end{document}
```

generates the following LaTeX code in out:

```
  % latex table generated in R 3.1.3 by xtable 1.7-4 package
  % Fri May  8 19:05:11 2015
  \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|}
    \hline
   & A & B & C \\
    \hline
  1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    3 & 111 & 222 & 33 \\
     \hline
  \end{tabular}
```

But I need the following

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|r|r|r|}
```

because I want to wrap this tabular into another one.

Is there a way to generate this optional position-code using xtable?

Answer (score 0):

As you have a text as a result, you could use regular expressions to insert `[t]` into `out`

For example using something like this:

```
outf<-gsub("(tabular}{+)", "tabular}[t]{", out, perl=TRUE)
```

Then you would get the following:

```
> cat(outf)
% latex table generated in R 3.2.0 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% 
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|r|r|r|}
  \hline
 & A & B & C \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  2 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\ 
  3 & 111 & 222 & 33 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: That would be okay. But I try to avoid these "regular expression hacks".